# Spring data Mongodb write operation from ApplicationRunner

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mongotemplate

I have a problem with writing to mongodb instance. Problem is that i can't write anything from this class.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemoDataWriter implements ApplicationRunner {
    private WarehouseRepository warehouseRepository;
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer1 = new Customer("Gleb", new Coordinate(4, 3));
        Customer customer2 = new Customer("Sasha", new Coordinate(8, 9));
        Customer customer3 = new Customer("Misha", new Coordinate(15, 10));

        Map<String, Integer> merchandiseQuantity1 = new HashMap<>();
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("computer", 16);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("bebra", 6);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("vacine", 10);
        Map<String, Integer> merchandiseQuantity2 = new HashMap<>();
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("laptop", 100);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("grivna", 20);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("beer", 1);
        Map<String, Integer> merchandiseQuantity3 = new HashMap<>();
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("cup", 13);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("chair", 90);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("notebook", 18);
        Map<String, Integer> merchandiseQuantity4 = new HashMap<>();
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("gun", 54);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("answer", 42);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("computer", 4);
        Map<String, Integer> merchandiseQuantity5 = new HashMap<>();
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("gun", 16);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("grinva", 6);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("charger", 132);
        Map<String, Integer> merchandiseQuantity6 = new HashMap<>();
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("computer", 16);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("bebra", 6);
        merchandiseQuantity1.put("vacine", 10);
        Warehouse warehouse1 = new Warehouse("Compluter Inc", merchandiseQuantity1, new Coordinate(43,12));
        Warehouse warehouse2 = new Warehouse("Bebra", merchandiseQuantity2, new Coordinate(21, 89));
        Warehouse warehouse3 = new Warehouse("LG", merchandiseQuantity3, new Coordinate(15, 90));
        Warehouse warehouse4 = new Warehouse("Abchihba", merchandiseQuantity4, new Coordinate(567, 890));
        Warehouse warehouse5 = new Warehouse("Node", merchandiseQuantity5, new Coordinate(389, 54));
        Warehouse warehouse6 = new Warehouse("Meta", merchandiseQuantity6, new Coordinate(321, 590));

        customerRepository.save(customer1);
        customerRepository.save(customer2);
        customerRepository.save(customer3);

        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse1);
        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse2);
        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse3);
        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse4);
        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse5);
        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse6);
    }
}
```

But i can write to database from Controller.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/customer/create")
public Customer createNewCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    System.out.println(customer.toString());
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
}
```

Maybe problem in my way of using spring for this logic and i just need to find different way for compliting such operation.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't write"? What error do you get?

Comment: I saw log that it's saving data, but after i couldn't get it from database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check whether u are able to go inside the run method in the debug mode.